# VBA module to check if list, contains two names from dynamic list

Tags: string, vba, list, loops

I'm trying to automate an accounting process. Every month I get a list of expenses, and I have to calculate teh total amount for each person. A cell will contain some text specifing what it is and which employee brought this item and the one next to will specify the amount.

I created a script that will look through the list and give me a total expense for each employee. The possible names are specified in a range in the document.

The problem is that a few of these cells will sometimes contain two names and the amount is then added to both employees total amount.

**Problem:**
Is it possible to create an If statement that will look through my list of names and "do something" if the cell contains **TWO** names from my list.

**EDIT:** This is the loop I already created

```
Sub AfstemLoop()
    Worksheets("Main").Activate

    Dim NamesAmount As Integer
    Dim NameString As String
    Dim TotalAmount As Double
    Dim TableStart As Integer

    'Count Amount of names
    NamesTotal = 0
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Worksheets("Main").Cells(i + 1, 7) <> "" Then
            NamesTotal = NamesTotal + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Count entries
    EntriesTotal = 0
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If Worksheets("Main").Cells(2 + i, 1) <> "" Then
            EntriesTotal = EntriesTotal + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Define table start
    TableStart = EntriesTotal + 4

    'Calculate total amount
    For i = 1 To NamesTotal
        TotalAmount = 0
        NameString = Worksheets("Main").Cells(i + 1, 7)
        For j = 1 To EntriesTotal
            CellText = Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 3)
            If InStr(1, CellText, NameString) Then
                Amount = Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 4)
                TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Amount
                    'Test to see if cell has been used (in case of spelling mistakes)
                    Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 4).Interior.Color = 5296274
            End If
        Next

        Worksheets("Main").Cells(TableStart + i, 3) = NameString
        Worksheets("Main").Cells(TableStart + i, 4) = TotalAmount
        Sum = TotalAmount + Sum
   Next

   Worksheets("Main").Cells(TableStart + NamesTotal + 1, 3) = "Total"
   Worksheets("Main").Cells(TableStart + NamesTotal + 1, 4) = Sum

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add the code you already have? It would make it easier to propose a solution.

Comment: I added the code I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check whether a name occurs and do stuff every time it happens:

```
For j = 1 To EntriesTotal
    CellText = Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 3)
    If InStr(1, CellText, NameString) Then
        Amount = Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 4)
        TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Amount
            'Test to see if cell has been used (in case of spelling mistakes)
            Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 4).Interior.Color = 5296274
    End If
Next
```

You want to change that so the code performs different tasks depending on the number of names in the cell. I suggest you introduce a name occurrence counter:

```
Dim namesInCellCount as long
namesInCellCount = 0

For j = 1 To EntriesTotal
    CellText = Worksheets("Main").Cells(j + 2, 3)
    If InStr(1, CellText, NameString) Then
        namesInCellCount = namesInCellCount + 1
    End If
Next

If namesInCellCount = 1 then
    'do your thing
ElseIf namesInCellCount > 1 then
    'do your other thing
End If
```

Just remember to reset the counter after you're done working with a cell (or before you start checking a new one). The `Dim` statement belongs at the top section of your code, beside other such statements.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late respons, had to post pone the work on this a bit. 

You were right though, I simply had to redo my if statements and check whether the cell countins multiple names and then perform the task., this solved my problem with some cells containing non or multiple names.